# mod_rewrite conditional redirect to snapshots

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want the server to return the prerendered content under certain conditions.

This works well

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _escaped_fragment_=
RewriteRule ^\/?(?!snapshots)(.+$) /snapshots/$1? [P,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

But if I add the useragent condition,

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*(vkShare).*$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _escaped_fragment_=
RewriteRule ^\/?(?!snapshots)(.+$) /snapshots/$1? [P,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

the server hangs for a long time and then returns an error 502 than I use specified useragent.

In access.log i see a lot of lines like this:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Oct/2015:23:46:36 +0300] "GET /snapshots/index.php HTTP/1.1" 502 563 "http://localhost/someurl" "vkShare"
```

Where is my mistake?

Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)

Comment: Watch Apache's error log while attempting this transaction. If Apache dislikes something, it ought to detail it in th elog.  The user agent match can be simplified considerably just to `RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} vkShare [OR]` which should save some resources, esp because you don't `()` capture `(vkShare)`

Comment: I use `P` flag for that customers should not see a changed URL